# chef knife search query

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, knife

my current search is `knife search node 'name:*  AND solr_cores_20170501*:*'`

I'd like to return data where the date can be either 20170501 or 20170508.  Thus far the ands, ors and ranges I've tried have failed.

Is is possible with knife?

Answer (score 0):

You want `solr_cores_20170501:* OR solr_cores_20170508:*` probably. In general you would want to do very complex filtering locally as we use Lucene in purely text mode with a lot of transforms on the data. Works well for simple cases but breaks down for the more complex stuff.